# How do I create a link to a specific portal on the Intel map?

Tags: ingress

I want to share a url that links to a specific portal on the http://ingress.com/intel map. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "pguid" key in the query string can be set to the GUID for a particular portal in order to highlight it.  Here is an example pointing to the Mosaic Sundial in Boulder:

- http://www.ingress.com/intel?latE6=40001583&lngE6=-105244818&z=14&pguid=fed178cb41794581874daeb2fae05f17.11

But note that this seems to be a feature that only works (so far? :) for the [IITC client](http://iitc.jonatkins.com/)

You can get this sort of link to a portal from IITC by clicking on the portal, and then clicking on the "portal link" link in the bottom left of the portal area:
[image]

Answer (score 5):

I know no way to reference a portal directly.

However you can create a link like this
http://www.ingress.com/intel?latE6=41380512&lngE6=2177417&z=19

Basically you have to find the coordinates of the portal you want to share and insert them into the link (you can use Google maps).

I hope either niantic labs or browser plugin developers will fix this in the coming future.

Comment: What browser plugins do you use with ingress? I was considering writing one that logged all of the RPC's lat longs and names from that site, and somehow generated the links for them (I'd use z=17 but I know ingress sends you super zoomed ones). Then shorten them with goo.gl, cross reference by ID, and add that information to the map so that the shortened URL can be seen in portal details, so they can be pasted in chats etc. A better solution would be a companion domain that has short links, and allows searching.

Comment: I am not using anything at the moment, but if you need help on your plugin suggestion please pm me.

Answer (score 4):

Although there is still no way to link directly to a portal, the Ingress Intel page does now have a "Map Link" function in the top right of the page:

[image: top right corner of the ingress intel page]

So, what I do is:

- Make my browser window small enough that both scroll bars appear.
- Zoom in as far down as I can, keeping the portal in the middle of the map.
- Take a link using the button at the top right.

By taking the link at the deepest zoom level with the smallest window size, it means that whatever size browser window someone is using, the portal should always be smack bang in the middle of the window.

Comment: If you have the portal selected in the Intel map, when you click on the link button, the 2nd set of coordinates (that begin with pll) are the portal location. This link will give you a direct link to a portal

Comment: This should be accepted as the correct answer at this time.

Answer (score 2):

I just did a little experiment expanding on [James S's comment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/95394/how-do-i-create-a-link-to-a-specific-portal-on-the-intel-map#comment227403_168231) and found out to my amazement that it's completely true. After that, I did another experiment and deleted the **"ll"** part from the link because I was thinking that this part corresponds to the center of the map that you're browsing and not to the portal being selected. (I think that it's the abbreviation for "location link" or "longitude latitude" while **pll** is the abbreviation for "portal location link" or "portal longitude latitude")

When you delete the **"ll"** part (including the coordinates) your link will be shortened and it still functions as a link.

Here is an example for the Statue of Liberty : https://www.ingress.com/intel?pll=40.689189,-74.044668